# objective c - UITableview refresh data when I scroll to top (without the need for pull to refresh)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to figure out the best method of implementing a UITableView refresh when the user scrolls to the top, without having the user pull down to refresh.

An example of this would be imessage app on the iPhone, when the user reaches top of messages, it displays the circular loading with a seemingly pulled down effect using the momentum of the scroll itself.

The regular refresh control requires a looong pull, which is something I don't want for the users.

Any tips on how to activate refresh control with minimal/no pull would be much appreciated.

Comment: your keyword is `infinite scroll`. you can find many questions here and articles on google.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

place refresh controller in scrollViewDidScroll

Comment: Please write this as `comment` or add some `code` for your solution.